# SQL Server update a cell to show duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table displaying some scanned `barcodes`. Each `barcode` has its own ID, and we will link all the `barcodes` scanned together using a foreign key we call `scanHeaderID` that will have the same `scanHeaderID` for each scan imported. I want to add a column to show whether the row is a duplicate within the same for those value with the same `scanHeaderID`.  Like so

```
ScanID | ScanHeaderID | Barcode | Duplicate
-------+--------------+---------+-------
 1     | 1            | 1111    | false
 2     | 1            | 2222    | true
 3     | 1            | 2222    | true
 4     | 1            | 3333    | false
 5     | 2            | 1111    | false
 6     | 2            | 5555    | false
```

`ScanID` 2 and 3 are marked as duplicate since they contain they same `barcode` in the same `ScanHeaderID`.  I need to add this column to a preexisting table and update the table to display these values for Scans that already exist.  I need to write SQL that will go through each row, and update the duplicate column base on this criteria.  I am not sure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once option is to use the window functions

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Duplicate = case when sum(1) over (Partition By ScanHeaderID,BarCode)>1 then 'true' else 'false' end
 From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ScanID  ScanHeaderID    Barcode Dupicate
1       1               1111    false
2       1               2222    true
3       1               2222    true
4       1               3333    false
5       2               1111    false
6       2               5555    false
```

**Edit - For the Update**

```
;with cte as ( 
    Select *
          ,NewVal = case when sum(1) over (Partition By ScanHeaderID,BarCode)>1 then 'true' else 'false' end
    From YourTable
)
Update cte Set Duplicate=NewVal
```

Comment: `Sum(1)` is the new `Count(*)`? :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Just seems "cleaner" to me.

Comment: @JSON Failed to mention, the CTE is used because a window function can only be used in a Select or Order By